# Reading PBF file or finding polygons of postcodes?

Tags: openstreetmap, postal-code

The issue: I want to find the polygons for the greek post codes.
I am not sure if this would help but I have just downloaded a PBF file from [geofabrik.de](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/greece.html#).
I installed osmconvert and OsmAndMapCreator, initialy so that I can see what this file contains and then find a way to use, if in fact has something usefull there, since I am not even sure if it has the information I need.
Using OsmAndMapCreator I haven't found a way to load my downloaded file. I think it is connected to openStreetMap site.
Using osmconvert on the other hand I have managed to read the file, but I only get nodes. no polygons.
for example when I transform the file to csv

```
osmconvert greece-latest.osm.pbf --all-to-nodes  --csv-headline --max-objects=35000000  >test.csv
```

and try to find the boundaries (which i suppose I should get the country,city etch boundaries)
`cat test.csv |grep boundary`
all I get is

> node  1000000046421309    Territorial water boundary between Greece and Turkey
>   node  1000000046421312    Territorial water boundary between Greece and Turkey
>   node  1000000082288606    Territorial water boundary between Greece and Turkey

So, is there a way to see if postcode polygons are in the file?
If there are not, is there a way to get the polygons from openstreetMap or any other place?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please refrain from asking two questions at once, since this complicates answering them. 1. QGIS is able to load the files from GeoFabrik. 2. OSM doesn't know the postal codes. 3. The "where to get the data" question is way better posted at OpenData.SE. 4. Postal codes should be provided by official sources in Greece.

Comment: @Erik first of all, thank you. So this file I have wouldnt have the postcodes. Good to know. The greek postal service has not opened the postal code information (as far as I know). They still think that its their property. Thanks

Comment: @SkarosIlias I highly recommend asking on [opendata.se] for help finding postcode data. Maybe Greece has something like in the US, where the postal service charges a high price for access to their database of up-to-date zip code areas, but you can get an approximation of zip code areas in the free "zip code tabulation areas" from the census bureau. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15620/19566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) for working with this data, especially since visualizing the data is easy and helpful to confirm what you do and do not have in the pbf extract.

When loading the pbf, these are the datatypes that QGIS recognizes in the linked data of Greece you posted:
[image]

This is a visual of what loaded:
[image]

Filtered multipolygons layer from QuickOSM Import of downloaded pbf:
"boundary" = 'postal_code'
[image]

So, there are some post-code boundaries in the file, but I do not know if they are even close to complete. It looks sparse to me.

7z of the extracted data:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvMZEGXuAwQzrbEoC3alhdbRehZ9DQ?e=luIFcm